# InnerHTML getting Div Name

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, innerhtml

I am trying to get a name of a DIV

```
<div id="test" name="info1" onclick="func(this.name)">This is div 1</div>
```

but when I try to print out the name of the div using innerHTML is comes back as undefined. Can this be done or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DIV.asp) a `div` cannot have a `name` attribute, but it can have an `id`, `class` or `title`. I think the DOM isn't recognising the attribute, therefore not making it available to Javascript.

I made an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/QmAgr/) which shows `title` working and `name` failing as you describe.

Comment: I would stick with id and class attributes.  They are most dependable.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to grab an attribute off a node is to use getAttribute as only a small subset of attributes are accessible directly (Title for instance can be, where as alt can't).

The getAttribute() method will also work fine with none standard attributes (which can be pretty useful at times)

The below code should pass it the nodes name to the func function correctly :)

```
<div id="test" name="info1" onclick="func(this.getAttribute('name')">This is div 1</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the name of the div, you should write some code that can get the attribute from an element (if you're not interested in cross-browser support just use elem.getAttribute)

For example:

```
    var getAttr = function(ele, attr) {
        var result = ele.getAttribute(attr) || ele[attr] || null, attrs, len;
        if( !result ) {
            attrs = ele.attributes;
            len = attrs.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
               if(attrs[i].nodeName === attr)
                  result = attrs[i].nodeValue;
        }
        return result;
};
```

Then you could do

```
<div id="test" name="info1" onclick="func(getAttr(this, 'name'))">This is div 1</div>
```